# getter-setter error #python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, getters-setters

Gostaria de saber onde está o erro nesse código supostamente simples

```
class Nome:
    def __init__(self,nome,sobrenome):
        self.__nome = nome # variável privada
        self.__sobrenome = sobrenome # variável privada
        self.nome_completo = nome + ' ' + sobrenome # variável pública
    def get_nome(self):
        return self.__nome
    def get_sobrenome(self):
        return self.__sobrenome
    def set_nome(self,novo_nome):
        self.__nome = novo_nome
    def set_nome(self,novo_sobrenome):
        self.__sobrenome = novo_sobrenome



a = Nome('Alan','Aragao')
a.set_nome('ovo')
a.get_nome()
```

quando eu executo o código, o nome 'ovo' não é retornado, e sim o nome 'Alan'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você definiu dois métodos `set_nome`, um está trocando o valor da propriedade `__nome` e o outro da propriedade `__sobrenome`:

```
def set_nome(self,novo_nome):
    self.__nome = novo_nome
def set_nome(self,novo_sobrenome):
    self.__sobrenome = novo_sobrenome
```

Com isso ao chamar o método set_nome:

```
a.set_nome('ovo')
```

Na verdade quem está sendo atualizada é a propriedade `__sobrenome`

---

Você pode corrigir o nome do método `set_nome` que atualiza a propriedade `__sobrenome` para `set_sobrenome`, corrigindo assim a situação:

```
def set_sobrenome(self,novo_sobrenome):
    self.__sobrenome = novo_sobrenome
```

---

Veja o exemplo com o seu código completo:

```
class Nome:
    def __init__(self,nome,sobrenome):
        self.__nome = nome # variável privada
        self.__sobrenome = sobrenome # variável privada
        self.nome_completo = nome + ' ' + sobrenome # variável pública

    def get_nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    def get_sobrenome(self):
        return self.__sobrenome

    def set_nome(self,novo_nome):
        self.__nome = novo_nome

    def set_sobrenome(self,novo_sobrenome):
        self.__sobrenome = novo_sobrenome


a = Nome('Alan','Aragao')
a.set_nome('ovo')

print("Nome:", a.get_nome())
print("Sobrenome:", a.get_sobrenome())
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/DirtyLimegreenThings

Comment: vish! passou despercebido heheh. Obrigado, amigo, boa sorte com seus projetos.